# Update multiple table from CSV in Cpdeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, csv

I am parsing a CSV file to add recrods to a table. this is how I do it.

```
foreach($csvData as $key => $row) {
            $data_n[$key] = array(
                'mf_date' => $row['mf_date'],
                'mf_work_id' => $row['mf_work_id'],
                'mf_sender' => $row['mf_sender'],
                'mf_amount' => $row['mf_amount'],
                'mf_trx_id' => $row['mf_trx_id'],
                );
            $this->db->insert('monthly_fee', $data_n[$key]);
        }
```

I have another table named `monthly_due` where there is three columns

```
1)md_work_id
2)md_ue
3)md_paid
```

I want to update two columns of that table with this operation. where mf_work_id matches with md_work_id want to update as

```
$md_due = $md_due - $row['mf_amount'];
md_paid = $md_paid + $row['mf_amount'];
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suppose you're working in a model of your application. I suppose that you want to achieve it in a safe mode, I mean, only if both queries are successful insert + update, and being totally sure that if the update isn't performed due to a problem with you database, your insert is rolled back and no data is inserted.

Well, safest way is using transaction: Taking into account that the tables of your database supports transactions (assuming innodb tables on a MySQL RMDB), this is what should work:

```
foreach($csvData as $key => $row) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $data_n[$key] = array(
        'mf_date' => $row['mf_date'],
        'mf_work_id' => $row['mf_work_id'],
        'mf_sender' => $row['mf_sender'],
        'mf_amount' => $row['mf_amount'],
        'mf_trx_id' => $row['mf_trx_id'],
    );
    $this->db->insert('monthly_fee', $data_n[$key]);

    // Now, you should check in the Database for the data
    $updData = array(
        'md_due'  => 'md_due + ' . $row['mf_amount']
    ,   'md_paid' => 'md_paid + ' . $row['mf_amount'] )

    $this->db->query("
         UPDATE monthly_due 
         SET md_due  = md_due  - $row['mf_amount']
           , md_paid = md_paid + $row['mf_amount']
         WHERE md_work_id = $row['mf_work_id']
    ");
    $this->db->trans_complete(); 
}
```

If you don't need transaction or your tables don't support it, you don't have to use `$this->db->trans_*` functions.

At the end the only modification in your code is adding the update sentence, which in SQL it's (numbers written just to substitute PHP values):

```
UPDATE monthly_due 
SET md_due  = md_due  - 23
  , md_paid = md_paid + 23 
WHERE md_work_id = 45
```

And with Codeigniter with active records should be the sentence written above.

Comment: how should I put the query in the loop? suppose I imported 10 data with loop where 4 of them are matched with 'monthly_due' table. so i have to put that query in a loop. same loop or another loop? how to pass fetched md_due md_paid in that loop?

Comment: The query is already put in the loop. I only wrote it below for showing how you can perform it directly against your database for testing purpose. About your CSV, you'll have 4 matches because you'll hit a row with the WHERE clause in the update. If you don't have it, you won't update anything.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
foreach($csvData as $key => $row) {
                $data_n[$key] = array(
                    'mf_date' => $row['mf_date'],
                    'mf_work_id' => $row['mf_work_id'],
                    'mf_sender' => $row['mf_sender'],
                    'mf_amount' => $row['mf_amount'],
                    'mf_trx_id' => $row['mf_trx_id'],
                    );
                if($this->db->insert('monthly_fee', $data_n[$key]))
                   {
                      $md_due = $md_due - $row['mf_amount'];
                      $md_paid = $md_paid + $row['mf_amount'];
                      $this->db->query("UPDATE monthly_due SET md_due='$md_due',md_paid='$md_paid' WHERE md_work_id = '$row['mf_work_id']'");


                   }
            }
```